# C# Cannot use Linq DefaultIfEmpty in ushort list items?

Tags: c#, linq, ushort

I want to take max value of ushort list and when that list is empty I want set "1" for default value.

For example:

```
List<ushort> takeMaxmumId = new List<ushort>();
var max = takeMaxmumId.Select(x=>x).DefaultIfEmpty(1).Max();
```

In my Example Visual Studio Show me this error:

> 'IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for
>   'DefaultIfEmpty' and the best extension method overload
>   'Queryable.DefaultIfEmpty(IQueryable, int)' requires a
>   receiver of type 'IQueryable'

When my list type were int I have not any problem, What is this problem in ushort type? And how can I fix this with best way?

Comment: Cast 1 to ushort.var max = takeMaxmumId.Select(x => x).DefaultIfEmpty( (ushort) 1).Max();

Comment: good answer when i cast its works fine, thank you

Comment: Or even shorter `var max = takeMaxmumId.DefaultIfEmpty((ushort)1).Max();`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `Select` produces an `IEnumerable<ushort>`, while `DefaultIfEmpty` supplies an `int` default. Hence, the types do not match.

You can fix this by forcing `ushort` type on the default:

```
var max = takeMaxmumId.Select(x=>x).DefaultIfEmpty<ushort>(1).Max();
//                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//            This part can be removed
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/np2RCn)

You can also convert sequence elements to `int`:

```
var max = takeMaxmumId.Select(x => (int)x).DefaultIfEmpty(1).Max();
```

Comment: You don't need the `Select`

Comment: best answer thank you,in my case I have a class that have a ushort property so i need use select in my case,but in this example we dont need "Select"

Comment: Don't have anywhere to test it, but could you also, these being generics, specify the type that way? `list.DefaultIfEmpty<ushort>().Max()?`

Comment: @Svish that's true, it will work, makes the code even cleaner.

Comment: @Svish Yes, that's even better, thank you very much for the comment!

Comment: @AliYousefie Don't forget to accept the answer that helped you the most.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this one:

```
 var max = takeMaximumId.DefaultIfEmpty((ushort)1).Select(x => x).Max();
```

The problem is due to the fact that passing 1 without the cast to `ushort` you can't apply the extension method `DefaultIfEmpty`, because 1 is interpreted as `int` and the list you want to apply this is of type `List<ushort>`. If you write the following

```
 var max = takeMaximumId.DefaultIfEmpty(1).Select(x => x).Max();
```

you would get the error message below, which explains the above

statement:

> 'List' does not contain a definition for 'DefaultIfEmpty' and
>   the best extension method overload
>   'Queryable.DefaultIfEmpty(IQueryable, int)' requires a
>   receiver of type 'IQueryable'

As a side note, despite the fact that dasblinkenlight has already mentioned this in his post, you don't need at all the `Select`, since you don't make any projection there. You just want to get the maximum value of the numbers contained in your list.

Answer (score 0):

Since your data type is ushort you will have to staisfy the alternative orverload of DefaultIfEmpty extension method. i.e DefaultIfEmpty(this IEnumerable source, TSource defaultValue);

So you will have to cast to your source to type ushort.

```
var max = takeMaxmumId.Select(x => x).DefaultIfEmpty( (ushort) 1).Max();
```